# GeoFireStore getLocation returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I tried to use GeoFireStore to set,get and query location.

I tried first to setLocation by using:

```
geoFirestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Locations");
geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(geoFirestoreRef);

geoFirestore.setLocation( auth.getUid(), new GeoPoint(Lat_Coordinate,Lon_Coordinate) );
```

It all worked good and created the following in my database:

[image]

Now, I tried to getLocation to see if it is working by using:

```
geoFirestore.getLocation( auth.getUid(), new GeoFirestore.LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(GeoPoint geoPoint, Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: "  + e);

    }
} );
```

and for some reason, it can't get anything eventho that I can see this location in my database.

I get the exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location doesn't exist`.

Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: where is the exception coming from? show full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the library too. When looking into the source, I saw a little [mistake here](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/blob/bec614bdc9110641cb9d699019855e56963d6067/geofirestore/src/main/java/org/imperiumlabs/geofirestore/GeoFirestore.kt#L192).

So I made a [pull request with the fix](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/pull/49). You can either use the fork link or clone the repository and fix line 192 with :

```
if (geoPoint != null)
```